# Displaying Count of Active Listing by different categories

Tags: mysql

In an online test, I tried to identify the number of live listings as on 2015-07-07. A listing is considered as a live listing if the auction date hasn't ended as of that date. The data schema is as follows :

[image]

I'm able to find the number of live listings by vertical, here is the code

```
select c.vertical, count(*) as Count_of_Live_Listings from Listing l 
inner join Category c on c.site_id = l.listing_site_id
and c.leaf_category_id = l.leaf_category_id
where l.auction_end_date < '2015-07-08'
group by c.vertical
```

and this is the output I get :
[Achieved Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPqUJ.jpg)

but not able to get the same data by seller segment, seller country as well.

The code I had tried is as follows (Excuse the syntax or conceptual errors) :

```
select (c.vertical, count(*) as Count_of_Live_Listings from Listing l 
inner join Category c on c.site_id = l.listing_site_id
and c.leaf_category_id = l.leaf_category_id
where l.auction_end_date < '2015-07-08'
group by c.vertical ), g1*
(select s.country, s.segment, count(*) as Count_of_Live_Listings from 
Listing l1
inner join Seller s on s.seller_id = l1.seller_id
where l.auction_end_date < '2015-07-08'
group by s.country, s.segment) g1
```

I got an error which said, "Incorrect syntax near group by or select"

I'm trying to provide the data (No. of live listings) by vertical, seller segment, seller country in a single table like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CDjf.jpg)

Is this possible in SQL ? Any other easier or less complicated way ?

I was thinking that using 'Union' is the only way to show these numbers in these 3 categories with one query, though one below the other. Any thoughts ?

Comment: You seem to know how to join tables and how to do group by. So, what prevents you to do all these with one more table and two more fields?

Comment: How do I join this output set with the seller table, and obtain the same numbers for Seller Segment and Seller Country ? When I use count *, grouping by number of vertical, i'm able to see the number of listings for the different verticals. Now, how do I get the same numbers for Seller Segment and Seller Country, without disturbing the count for vertical ? I'm able to do these separately, but all three categories and number of listings together, is something that I'm not able to achieve right now

Comment: What do you mean by not disturbing the count for vertical? Pls provide sample data and expected output. Pls also provide how you tried to bring the seller data in and what went wrong with that query.

Comment: This was an online test I took a day earlier, so do not have the actual error message, but I've added more details like you've suggested. Please have a look

Comment: I don't think its possible if you want to show the output side by side like that.

Comment: Simply because there are no relationship. If I had to guess, the other two query you grouped by `Seller_segment & Seller_country`, correct? If you join these three queries, what will be the relationship between those three results? You know you can't match `vertical` with `Seller_segment` nor `Seller_country`. Unless... I misunderstand your question. Do you want to get the results show separately by separate query or combined results in one query?

Comment: I agree with @tcadidot0, this is not really possible in sql. You can hack a resultset like this together, but the individual records would have absolutely no meaning. You can produce the counts by vertical, country and segment and can aggregate whichever column you want further - this is the typical OLAP cube design. I suggest you look into the `with rollup` modifier (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) because it can produce the data points you are after, but in a way that it makes more sense.

Comment: Thank you @tcadidot0,  and Shadow, I'm quite new to SQL querying, and since I wasn't able to get this kind of an output, I thought there might exist a way to show the different numbers across the three categories side by side. It feels good that I wasn't too far off, in my conclusion. To show these results in a single query, I also thought about Union, and that is the only way to show them in a single page, though, one below the other right ?

Comment: @Barath yes, union is a way to show the counts below each other.

Comment: Actually, when I think about it, there is a way to make it happen; by assigning row number for each of the syntax and use that as a relation to do `LEFT JOIN` > where the query that have the most rows will be the LEFT table. But as far as this goes, it still doesn't count as a valid relation. And it's not a long term solution. It's only for the sake of showing the result as how your expected output is. Wait, am I allowed to give you this idea?

Comment: Yes, it was an online test I didn't complete, so any ideas now are welcome, there were four more tasks with the same schema, and as a newbie, I didn't stand a chance to complete them in time. I guess I should have used Union. At least I could have got all the numbers using a query.